# malloc in C++ for performance

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, memory, malloc

I'm optimizing a computationally intensive part of a program that has performance as a priority.

Currently I am using std::array for various types of data and caches that cannot be initialized immediately. I would like to allocate the memory for the cache **without default initializing the elements** for the sake of performance, so that I can initialize them with the appropriate values once they have been computed. The only way I could think of doing that is using malloc. Are there any "cleaner" ways of accomplishing this, and is this a justifiable use of malloc in C++?

I'm aware of the common advice of "never use malloc/new[]". There is a demonstrable need for optimization based on measurements. This is not premature optimization. This part of the code is called ~2.5 million times per second on each thread, and each call should run in under 1000 nanoseconds.

Comment: The optimal choice would be to allocate once before reaching this part of the code and avoid allocation/reallocation within this critical section altogether. There is nothing wrong with `malloc` or `new` for that matter. The difference, among other things, is `malloc` knows nothing about object construction. If you just allocate for a block of "plain-old-type", then malloc is fine. If what you allocate relies on a constructor to further allocate, etc.., then `new` is your choice. Yes, this would be a valid use of `malloc` if you cannot pre-allocate/construct something else.

Comment: Are you allocating `std::array` on the heap 2.5 million times per second right now, before the optimization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allocate an array of bytes that is large enough to hold the maximum number of elements you want to eventually construct. You can then use [`placement-new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) whenever you want to construct an object at a given byte offset within the array.

You can alternatively use [`std::aligned_storage`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) as the array element type instead of using raw bytes. The linked documentation even provides an example of this exact technique.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to cleanly allocate an `std::array` without initialising it and without resorting to C-style APIs or low-level APIs like `aligned_storage`.

```
#include <memory>
#include <array>

template <class T> struct uninit : public T
{
    uninit() {} // do not omit, do not make = default.
};

using myarray = std::array<int, 1337>;
using myarray_uninit = uninit<myarray>;

std::unique_ptr<myarray> allocate_myarray()
{
    return std::make_unique<myarray_uninit>();
}
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Tvvzab9rq)

This particular answer is not concerned with the performance of allocating stuff on the heap vs the performance of *not* allocating stuff on the heap.

Comment: Could you explain why the uninit struct does not initialize the elements of the array it is derived from? Why does an empty constructor without initializer list prevent the base class from calling its constructor, and shouldn't this be identical to the implicitly generated constructor? From the standard: "The implicitly-defined default constructor performs the set of initializations of the class that would be performed by a user-written default constructor for that class with no ctor-initializer (12.6.2) and an empty
compound-statement."

Comment: It does not initialize the elements because the base class does not have an explicit constructor, so it is default-initialised. However if you default or omit the ctor, the entire class becomes a POD and will be zero-initialised. I just love C++ sometimes.

Comment: Thanks, one more question: according to the standard, members that are not initialized in the ctor-list initializer are default initialized. So shouldn't the implicit default constructor of the base default initialize all of its members, as it does not have a ctor-list initializer? This would mean the c-style array that is part of the base class would be default initialized, but the standard also says that "to default-initialize an array type means each element is default-initialized." which would be the result we are trying to avoid. Could you point out where the flaw in my logic is here?

Comment: No we are trying to avoid zero-initialization, not default-initialization.

Comment: Okay, I see what you’re saying. I was assuming this solution would work in general, but it only does for arrays of trivial types.

Comment: That's right, I assumed that you need exactly that. If not, I apologise.

Comment: Note that for classes with construcrors there will be no zero initialization. If your class defines a default constructor that does nothing, that's what be called. And this is exactly why I defined an empty ctor in this example.